# Круглая рамка возле квадратной иконки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Вопрос возможно довольно простой, но тк иконки квадратные не получается сделать круглую рамку возле иконки, надо сделть красную иконку с белым бордером по кругу.

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.fa-circle {
  color: red;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="ind">
  <i class="fa  fa-circle  hr"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно сделать.
Сначала задаём рамку для нашег округа тегом `border`, устанавливаем размер в `2px`, задаём сплошуную линияю ( `solid` ), цвет `white`. Ставим `border-radius:100%;`. Закрашиваем весь  `background-color: red;` в красный.
И вуаля!

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.fa-circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  color: red;
  background-color: red;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.fa-circle::before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="ind">
  <div class="fa-circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Проблема в том, обратите внимание на форму рамки и иконки, рамка не прилегает полностью

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев я вас понял, код поменял.

Comment: Cпасибо, это конечно уже придирки, но можете сделать иконку с одинаковыми сторонами?:D сейчас 17.5 px на 20 px Она просто в положение авто ставит размеры, фиг пойми, как это изменить

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев а что за класс `ind`?

Comment: он для передвижения

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев посмотрите, я изменил код, это то что вы хотели?

Comment: Да, спасибо!....

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев Рад помочь :)